# Строчная или прописная: кануть в (Л)ету

Tags: орфография

Тут как-то задавался вопрос о ящике Пандоры, и выяснилось, что "Пандора" пишется с прописной буквы. А как быть с выражением "кануть в (Л)ету"? Лета - тоже имя собственное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь тонкий момент. Выражение "кануть в Лету" не приобрело статуса окончательно сложившегося фразеологизма, в котором значение целого не вытекает из значений составляющих. В отличие от "ящика Пандоры" или, скажем, "уз Гименея" и прочего.

Дело в том, что "Лета" само по себе приобрело нарицательное значение "забвение". Отсюда и его использование с написанием со строчной буквы в текcтах многих авторов. Т.е. они воспринимают "кануть в лету" как состоящее из двух слов, имеющих обычное значение, а весь оборот как устойчивое сочетание, не пререшедшее в разряд фразеологизмов.

Тем не менее я с позиций современного языка считал бы "Лету" в таком выражении именем собственным - и использовал бы заглавную.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно. Лета - название реки (река забвения в царстве Аида). Из "Грамоты": *Лета, -ы (мифол.; кануть в Лету)*

Answer (score 1):

В словаре А.К.Бириха и др. "Русская фразеология. Историко-этимологический словарь", на сайте "Грамота.ру": *кануть в **Л**ету*. А вот в *примерах*, приведенных во Фразеологическом словаре под ред.Молоткова, пишется "кануть в **л**ету": Оно *канет в лету* вместе с объявлениями газетными о пилюлях и не будет о том и речи (Гоголь); Твоих друзей *не канут в лету* Бесчисленные имена (М.Дудин); Эта иллюзия заставляла спорщиков забывать, что событие, о котором они говорят, описано, может быть, еще год назад и давно *кануло в лету* (М.Новорусский).

Несмотря на некоторый разнобой, я бы все-таки писала имя собственное в прописной буквы, как того требуют словари.

Comment: Помнится, в русском языке немало слов и выражений, в которых исходное имя собственное приобрело нарицательное значение: "сизифов труд, авгиевы конюшни..." Не случайно в ответе olsa приводится много примеров с "лету". Я ни разу не встречал это слово с прописной буквой